# C# webbrowser how to access HtmlElement CSS class?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to fill out a web form. How do we access a class of HTML element in html? Normally we use this code:

```
webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById
```

The html is below:

```
<select class="birthday_day" name="birthday_day" >
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: -1: for "different things" is very hard to reason why it did not work. Consider minimal (one line usually enough) code showing what you tried. Try not to use terms that means totally different things (like class) without clarification.

Comment: `i tried different things it wont work out!` for example?

Comment: i know you feel bad because you failed to provide me with a helpful example. You just gave me a link to msdn example like i did not try that thing before haan?  By the way how do i -1 you?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do it by name, not class, so you could try using the Document.All property:

```
webBrowser2.Document.All["birthday_day"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using getAttribute - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute.aspx both CLASS and NAME should be available.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since it's rather hard to find:
As previously mentioned `GetAttribute` is part of the answer. The trick is to use the correct attribute name:

```
var element = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("birthday_day");
var classes = element.GetAttribute("className"); // instead of just "class"
```

This is not a quirk of the WebBrowser control, but legacy of the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) from back when it was a huge problem to have keywords such as `class` as property names in JavaScript.